# How to use jest.mock with different mock implementations for each it() test case in Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, mocking

I'm writing unit tests for my Node.js application using Jest, and I need to use jest.mock to mock a middleware function for each individual it() test case. I want to provide different mock implementations for the middleware function in different test cases.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```js
// My test file

// Import the required modules first (e.g., request and app)
const request = require('supertest');
const app = require('../../../path/to/your/app');

it("Should return a 200 status code if at least one image exists in the temp directory.", async () => {
  // Mock the middleware for this specific test case
  jest.mock('../../../middleware/awsTransferMiddleware', () => ({
    transferS3Files: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (req, res, next) => {
      // Custom mock implementation for this test case
    }),
    filterPassedImage: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (req, res, next) => {
      // Custom mock implementation for this test case
    }),
  }));

  // Test implementation for this test case goes here
});

it("Should test another scenario with a different mock for the middleware.", async () => {
  // Mock the middleware with a different implementation for this test case
  jest.mock('../../../middleware/awsTransferMiddleware', () => ({
    transferS3Files: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (req, res, next) => {
      // Different custom mock implementation for this test case
    }),
    filterPassedImage: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (req, res, next) => {
      // Different custom mock implementation for this test case
    }),
  }));

  // Test implementation for this test case goes here
});
```

The issue is that jest.mock doesn't appear to fully mock the middleware unless I place them outside the it() function.

By placing it outside the `it()` function, the mocked version will be applied to all `it()` functions.

I already checked the related questions (spyOn solution, ...), and didn't work.

Is there a way to use jest.mock or another approach in Jest to achieve different mock implementations for each it() test case without affecting other test cases? I want to test my endpoint with various scenarios and behaviors using specific mock implementations tailored to each test case.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Mocks can be tricky. Here is the strategy I always use:

- Always `jest.mock(...)` the library or function in the top-level of the test. This won't be sufficient alone to dynamically but it is a needed first step. See [here](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mocking-modules) for details.

  ```js
  jest.mock('../../../middleware/awsTransferMiddleware')
  ```

  You'll also need to import it to do a `spyOn` later.

  ```js
  const awsTransferMiddleware = require('../../../middleware/awsTransferMiddleware')
  ```
- Use an `afterEach()` block to restore and clear all mocks after each test, like so:

  ```js
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks()
    jest.clearAllMocks()
  })
  ```

  This will allow us to change the mock implementation for each test without affecting the other tests ([Docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestclearallmocks))
- Finally, I find it easiest to create a top-level variable for each mock (like this: `let mockedModuleSpy` and then to reassign that variable at the beginning of each function, like this:

  ```js
  it("Should return a 200 status code if at least one image exists in the temp directory.", async () => {
    // Mock the middleware for this specific test case
    mockedModuleSpy = jest.spyOn('getPermissionInstitutions').mockImplementation(() => ({
      transferS3Files: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (req, res, next) => {
        // Custom mock implementation for this test case
      }),
      filterPassedImage: jest.fn().mockImplementation(async (req, res, next) => {
        // Custom mock implementation for this test case
      }),
    }));

    // Test implementation for this test case goes here
  });
  ```

Let me know if that works for you!